# what's a good strategy for identifying the problematic file on a nosetest ImportError?

Tags: python, nose

let's say I have a directory with 3 test*.py files.

```
__init__.py
lib1.py
lib2.py
test_01.py
test_02_badimport.py
test_03.py
```

`nosetest` by itself just runs all the tests.

Now, let's say also that one of the tests, **test_02_badimport.py** has an issue with an import.  This is the code for it, though it's not super-important:

```
import unittest

#this module is missing, so it will trigger an ImportError
import missing_module

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This is what I get from doing a `nosetests`:

```
(env) me@test_nose$ nosetests
nose.config: INFO: Ignoring files matching ['^\\.', '^_', '^setup\\.py$']
test_basic (test_nose.test_01.MyTest) ... ok
test_something (test_nose.test_01.MyTest) ... ok
Failure: ImportError (No module named missing_module) ... ERROR
test_basic (test_nose.test_03.MyTest) ... ok
test_something (test_nose.test_03.MyTest) ... ok

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named missing_module)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/Users/me/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/Users/me/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Users/me/wk/explore/test_nose/test_02_badimport.py", line 3, in <module>
    import missing_module
ImportError: No module named missing_module

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.007s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Look at `Failure: ImportError (No module named missing_module) ... ERROR`.  Now, I know that it it's caused by **import missing_module**.

But it requires a fair bit of tracking to figure out that the problem lies with test_02_badimport.py, because that information is not communicated to the test run output, it's only part of the stack trace dump.

My actual case was more complicated, it's due to a circular import issue in the context of a django.setup() call, so my own code appears both interleaved with nose and unittest code, as well as Django files, in the midst of a huge stack trace, rather than at the bottom as in this example.

Is there any way to achieve something like:

`(test_nose.test_02_badimport) Failure: ImportError (No module named missing_module) ... ERROR` in the output?

Or do I just have to pay attention to the next line **after** the nose load_module call in the stack trace?

```
  File "/Users/me/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
```

Following the above, **test_02_badimport.py** is the guilty file:

```
  File "/Users/me/wk/explore/test_nose/test_02_badimport.py", line 3, in <module>
    import missing_module
```

**My workflow:**

Nosetest, especially with the `-x` (stop on first error) flag allows me to quickly run all tests.  And, once I know which test_xxx.py file has a problem I can run it from the command line `python test_02_badimport.py` directly and fix it.  In most cases, that works very well, but ImportError somewhat hides the filename.

Is there a commandline switch?  (I tried `--collect-only` but that didn't help)?  Neither did `nosetests --debug=nose,nose.importer --debug-log=nose_debug`.

Or a plugin?

Failing that, is the next line after `mod = load_module` always going to show my problem test file?

Comment: In nothing else, you should be able to write a shell or python program to run nose separately on each `test*.py` in the directory.

Comment: True, but... nose itself is almost there, isn't it?

Comment: I posted by suggestion as a comment because I don't know enough about nose to properly answer whether there is a better, more proper way. I hope an experience nose user will see this.